# MVC display foreign key from another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.AccountType = new BusinessLayer.AccountTypeManager().GetAccountTypes();
        return View(new BusinessLayer.AccountManager().getAccount(id));
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="display-label">Account Type</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.AccountType)</div><br />
```

This current view displays the AccountType ID. How can I display the AccountType Name which is being passed by the ViewBag.AccountType (IEnumerable)

Answer (score 0):

something like following

```
<div class="display-label">Account Type</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.AccountType)</div>
@{
    var TypeNames = ViewBag.AccountType as IEnumerable<string>;

    foreach(var item in TypeNames)
    {
        <div>item</div>
    }
}
```

Mode elegant way

```
public class AccountTypeVewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> typeNames { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    AccountTypeVewModel model = new AccountTypeVewModel();
    model.typeNames = new BusinessLayer.AccountTypeManager().GetAccountTypes();
    model.account = new BusinessLayer.AccountManager().getAccount(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

view

```
<div class="display-label">Account Type</div>
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.account.AccountType)</div>
@{
    foreach(var item in Model.typeNames)
    {
        <div>item</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: no need for foreach. I think you did not understand me.
View Bag contains the following: ID - 1 Name - Fixed. ID - 2 Name - Current.
Now the current @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => etc..) displays 1 or 2 for example. How can I change that 1 or 2 to Fixed or Current?